# Windows Server authentication precedence within domain but between sites

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, permissions, network-share

My overall goal for the following was to understand which domain servers (local or primary) actually control authentication for a share or folder.

I'll start by describing my setup:

---

2 sites, A and B
Site A: The primary domain controller ("Primary"), and my workstation ("Workstation")
Site B: Local domain controller that is also a file server ("Branch"). It has a hard drive S:\ on which shared folders are created.

(All servers are Windows Server 2008 R2. Site A also has a secondary domain controller, however that might affect my question.)

---

I have a shared folder on Branch\S: ("FolderX") and I've set the Share permissions to Everyone, full control; and Security permissions to Domain Admins and an AD group ("GroupX") which has "Modify".
As a domain admin, I can get into the folder from Branch.

I attempt to access the folder from Workstation as my regular user account, and cannot. (\Branch\FolderX) I can go to \Branch, and I see FolderX among the shares.

Prior to replication, **from which domain controller should I need to add my regular user account to GroupX in order to access FolderX?**
(That was my actual question, which I thought would be easy to determine via experimentation. However... )

If I add my regular user account to GroupX while logged into Branch, I cannot access the folder from Workstation. (i.e. My regular user account does not yet exist in GroupX in AD on Primary.)

I remove my regular user account from GroupX on Branch.

I then add my regular user account to GroupX while logged into Primary. I still cannot access \Branch\FolderX from Workstation.

If I make sure my regular user account exists in GroupX in AD on both Branch and Primary, I still cannot access FolderX.

*What am I missing?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the domain controllers.  It's the kerberos ticket on your workstation.  To simplify, when your kerberos ticket was issued (when you logged in, probably), it enumerated your group memberships then.  (There's a longer description [here](http://windowsitpro.com/security/q-how-does-windows-learn-about-my-group-memberships-when-i-log-windows-forest-how-authoriza).)  Your group memberships won't be updated until the ticket expires or you log off and log back on.

To answer the implied question:  Add yourself to the group on Branch and then log out and back in on your workstation.  (You could also purge your kerberos tickets, but I think that's moving beyond the scope of this answer.)